# Proving Inequality Using Graph

Tags: real-analysis

> Given: 0 < a < b, Prove: $\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} < \frac{1}{3}(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{b}})$

As usual, we need to start from one side and reach the other by deduction. However, I am not sure I am going to get there. The solution may require Calculus but not to a highly advanced level.

The graph of $y=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is:

[image]

This shows us that the mean value of the function between a and b is less than the mean of f(a) and f(b) as the graph is concave.

In other words:

For the range $[a,b]$,

$f_{mean} \ne \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$

Comment: By letting $b=B^2, a=A^2$ with $A>B>0$ your inequality turns out to be equivalent to
$$ 3AB(B-A) < (B^3-A^3) $$
or to
$$ 3AB < B^2+AB+A^2 $$
or to $(B-A)^2>0$, which is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite like this (divide by $ab$):  $${1\over \sqrt{b}} -  {1\over \sqrt{a}} < \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}-\frac{1}{b\sqrt{b}})$$
and then 
 $${1\over \sqrt{b}} +\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{b\sqrt{b}} < \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}+{1\over \sqrt{a}}$$
If we put $a'={1\over \sqrt{a}}$ and $b'={1\over \sqrt{b}}$
then we get $0<b'<a'$ and
$$3b' + b'^3 <3a'+a'^3$$

Now observe

$$f(x) = 3x+x^3 $$

Since $f'(x) =3+3x^2>0$ the $f$ is strictly increasing and thus conclusion.